# Как показывать сайт спустя секунд 8?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui

сейчас сайт загрузился, а лоадер еще крутится

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('body').addClass('loaded_hiding');
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    $('body').addClass('loaded');
    $('body').removeClass('loaded_hiding');
  }, 3000);

});
```

```css
.preloader {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 1001;
}

.preloader__image {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  margin-top: -32px;
  margin-left: -32px;
  background: url("preloader.gif") no-repeat 50% 50%;
}

.loaded_hiding .preloader {
  transition: 3s opacity;
  opacity: 0;
}

.loaded .preloader {
  display: none;
}

section {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preloader">
  <div class="preloader__image">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/RyxkGMj/contact-form-loader.gif" alt="">
  </div>
</div>

<section class="content1">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, repudiandae, saepe commodi voluptatum ratione nostrum. Placeat, iusto perferendis incidunt magnam illo deserunt id odio laborum, dolorum non quas harum nesciunt.
</section>

<section class="content2">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, repudiandae, saepe commodi voluptatum ratione nostrum. Placeat, iusto perferendis incidunt magnam illo deserunt id odio laborum, dolorum non quas harum nesciunt.
</section>

<section class="content3">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, repudiandae, saepe commodi voluptatum ratione nostrum. Placeat, iusto perferendis incidunt magnam illo deserunt id odio laborum, dolorum non quas harum nesciunt.
</section>

<section class="content4">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, repudiandae, saepe commodi voluptatum ratione nostrum. Placeat, iusto perferendis incidunt magnam illo deserunt id odio laborum, dolorum non quas harum nesciunt.
</section>
```

Comment: Не очень понял смысл вопроса, но если что - загрузка страницы определяется по $(window).load, а не $(document).ready

Comment: сейчас загрузился основной контент - а лоадер еще крутится (а его нужно скрывать), лоадер показывать нужно секунд 8

Comment: @Fozzy так происходит потому что, мало того что событие не верное, так ещё и вначале вы  body добавляете класс loaded_hiding, который в любом раскладе за 3 секунды делает прозрачным лоадер

Comment: так правильно ? https://jsfiddle.net/L2mu7c4o/6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы, что-то напутали... Лучше изменить так:

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    $('body').addClass('loaded');
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
.preloader {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 1001;
}

.preloader__image {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  margin-top: -32px;
  margin-left: -32px;
  background: url("preloader.gif") no-repeat 50% 50%;
}

.loaded .preloader {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 3s opacity, 3s visibility;
}

section {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preloader">
  <div class="preloader__image">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/RyxkGMj/contact-form-loader.gif" alt="">
  </div>
</div>

<section class="content1">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, repudiandae, saepe commodi voluptatum ratione nostrum. Placeat, iusto perferendis incidunt magnam illo deserunt id odio laborum, dolorum non quas harum nesciunt.
</section>

<section class="content2">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, repudiandae, saepe commodi voluptatum ratione nostrum. Placeat, iusto perferendis incidunt magnam illo deserunt id odio laborum, dolorum non quas harum nesciunt.
</section>

<section class="content3">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, repudiandae, saepe commodi voluptatum ratione nostrum. Placeat, iusto perferendis incidunt magnam illo deserunt id odio laborum, dolorum non quas harum nesciunt.
</section>

<section class="content4">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, repudiandae, saepe commodi voluptatum ratione nostrum. Placeat, iusto perferendis incidunt magnam illo deserunt id odio laborum, dolorum non quas harum nesciunt.
</section>
```